# Bash replace string with contents from second file

Tags: string, bash, replace, sed, awk

I have two files one that looks like this:

`FILE1`

```
>comp0_c0_seq1 len=392 path=[1:0-391]
ATGAG...
>comp1_c0_seq1 len=399 path=[1:0-398]
AAGGA...
>comp1_c1_seq1 len=589 path=[1319:0-588]
TATAT...
>comp2_c0_seq2 len=340 path=[1:0-339]
GGAGT...
>comp2_c1_seq1 len=312 path=[924:0-311]
GGTTA...
>comp2_c1_seq2 len=312 path=[924:0-311]
TTATT...
>comp4_c0_seq1 len=800 path=[1:0-581 1284:582-799]
AGAGA...
>comp6_c0_seq1 len=245 path=[815:0-151 745:152-244]
GATTA...
```

And a second file

`FILE2`

```
>contig_1
>contig_2
>contig_3
>contig_4
>contig_5
>contig_6
>contig_7
>contig_8
```

I can't find a pattern in `FILE1` so I could easily replace the `>comp0_c0_seq1` part with `>contig_1` and so on. `FILE2` has no sequences, only the headers

I've been trying with `sed` and `awk` but I haven't succeed

the output I wish to get is:

```
>contig_1 len=392 path=[1:0-391]
ATGAG...
>contig_2 len=399 path=[1:0-398]
AAGGA...
>contig_3 len=589 path=[1319:0-588]
TATAT...
>contig_4 len=340 path=[1:0-339]
GGAGT...
>contig_5 len=312 path=[924:0-311]
GGTTA...
>contig_6 len=312 path=[924:0-311]
TTATT...
>contig_7 len=800 path=[1:0-581 1284:582-799]
AGAGA...
>contig_8 len=245 path=[815:0-151 745:152-244]
GATTA...
```

The files I'm working with are >30,000 contigs long, with very large sequences in between them.

Comment: so you just want to replace the nth sequence with nth contig?

Comment: yes, that is correct.

Comment: I want to replace the ambiguous name between ">" and "len=# path=[]" Keeping the sequence between contigs.

Comment: is `comp[\d]_c[\d]_seq[\d]`  and `contig_[\d]` valid regexes for your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk '{ if(/comp/) { getline $1 < "input2"; } print }' input1
```

Comment: Amazing! I looked for this answer for three days! Thank you so much!

Comment: Not that I'd do it this way but the condition should really go outside the block `awk /comp/{getline $1<"input2"}1' input1`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` without the headache of `getline` and using both files:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next}/^>comp/{$1=a[++i]}1' file2 file1
>contig_1 len=392 path=[1:0-391]
ATGAG...
>contig_2 len=399 path=[1:0-398]
AAGGA...
>contig_3 len=589 path=[1319:0-588]
TATAT...
>contig_4 len=340 path=[1:0-339]
GGAGT...
>contig_5 len=312 path=[924:0-311]
GGTTA...
>contig_6 len=312 path=[924:0-311]
TTATT...
>contig_7 len=800 path=[1:0-581 1284:582-799]
AGAGA...
>contig_8 len=245 path=[815:0-151 745:152-244]
GATTA...
```

This assumes the `file1` and `file2` have the same number of `>comp0_c0_seq1` and `>contig_8`.

---

If you just want increasing `>contig_` then you don't need `file2` at all:

```
$ awk '/^>comp/{$1=">contig"++i}1' file1
>contig1 len=392 path=[1:0-391]
ATGAG...
>contig2 len=399 path=[1:0-398]
AAGGA...
>contig3 len=589 path=[1319:0-588]
TATAT...
>contig4 len=340 path=[1:0-339]
GGAGT...
>contig5 len=312 path=[924:0-311]
GGTTA...
>contig6 len=312 path=[924:0-311]
TTATT...
>contig7 len=800 path=[1:0-581 1284:582-799]
AGAGA...
>contig8 len=245 path=[815:0-151 745:152-244]
GATTA...
```

Comment: but this can potentially use a lot of memory

Comment: The first solution we are talking 3 kilobytes max, hardly an issue with todays hardware. Anyway the use of `file2` isn't needed at all I only included the first script as an alternative to the use of `getline`. The second script should be used here.

Comment: Thank you! the last solution saves me the step of finding out how many contigs each file has. Both perreal's and your answers are excelent :D

Answer (score 0):

A Python 2.7 solution (pulls all of FILE1 into memory so perreal's solution should be your first option)

```
from __future__ import print_function
import re

pat = re.compile('(>comp.*?) .*?(?=(>comp|\Z))', re.DOTALL)
with open('FILE1') as f, open('FILE2') as f2:
  data = f.read()
  for fragment in pat.finditer(data):  
    fragment = fragment.group(0).replace(fragment.group(1), next(f2).rstrip())
    print(fragment, end='')
```

Comment: `print` is a statement in Python 2.7 this looks like a Python 3 solution?

Comment: @sudo_O, see the `from __future__ import print_function` at the beginning